# Rename the APK file with its packageName + versionCode + versionName

Tags: linux, apk, rename

I have the APK files which are named by their versionCode (default policy, APKs were pulled directly from Google).

Running this command -- *aapt dump badging apk-name.apk | grep package:\ name* -- gets me its package name, versionCode and versionName, all of three are needed in new name.

Let's take a Google Maps files as an example. I have this file 964100232.apk, for which I if I run this command -- aapt dump badging 964100232.apk | grep package:\ name -- it gives me this output:

package: name='com.google.android.apps.maps' versionCode='964100232' versionName='9.64.1' platformBuildVersionName='8.1.0'

My maps files is named 964100232.apk, and I need it to be com.google.android.apps.maps-964100232-9.64.1.apk

I need a command/script on Linux which allows me to rename all the APK files in the directory recursively, but the new name should be in package name-versionCode-versionName format.

Please help with this. I need this on Linux mainly, but would a windows fix would also make-do.

Thanks!

Comment: your question does not relate to `android`,`apk`,`aapt`. You just need to rename general file

Comment: It has to use the aapt tool to get the details for renaming the file. So, I thought it is related to aapt.
Should I change the tags?

Comment: but you already did this, right? So now you don't need to know about aapt anything else.

Comment: okay, edited the question, added more info, and kept only rename tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the apk name by the build.gradle file

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        lintOptions {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
        }
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->

                def flavor = "Test";
                if (variant.productFlavors.size() > 0)
                    flavor = variant.productFlavors.get(0);

                def finalName = flavor.applicationId + "-" + variant.buildType.name + "-v" + variant.versionName + '-' + variant.versionCode + ".apk";
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, finalName)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: uh-oh ... thanks a ton.. uh, but no knowledge of gradle or Android Studio here ... so, kindly suggest a BAT script or SH script.

Comment: No knowledge about BAT script or SH script.

Answer (score 0):

APK Batch Rename Tool recursively crawls input folder and all of its subfolders looking for Android Package files (.apk's). It reads Label and Version info from apk's found and creates a copy for each apk under the output folder but using the Label and Version info acquired............

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/apk-batch-rename-tool-for-windows-and-linux.841312/